# Executing ssh commands in bash script

Tags: bash, ssh, terminal

I need to execute the ff. commands in my bash script but when I do, it stops after logging in to ssh (ssh -A test.ou.monix.com ). Can someone help me with the commands for these?

Thanks!

```
ssh-add
ssh -A test.ou.monix.com 
screen
dbtest
sudo su
mysql -u root
use mobile1
```

Comment: See: [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)

Comment: do commands like `sudo` allow heredoc over ssh?

Comment: @anishsane: I'm not sure and reopened this question.

Comment: Worst case, `expect` should work...

Comment: Perhaps `ssh -tt`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell "ff." means "following" sorry